# sending variables to procedures in c and pascal

Tags: c, pascal, procedure

for sending variables to procedures what we should do in c and(or) pascal?
as i searched this work has to be done by BP( base pointer)
or rather i should say that BP do it,and one more thing is that C and Pascal are opposite of each other.

Comment: i don´t understand the text ... what do you try to tell or ask us?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake from me.
the problem i have is that i need at least an example of how base pointer work with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is entirely unclear. It would appear that you *might* be asking about C and Pascal calling conventions on the x86 architecture (at least your mention of `BP` hints at this).

If that's the case, I'd recommend you study the [Wikipedia page on x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), and come back when you have specific questions.

**edit** You might also want to check out [X86 Assembly/High-Level Languages](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/High-Level_Languages) along with the "Further Reading" links therein.